Can 'ones' be used to refer to plural nouns without any written context?

context: Holding a bag of potato chips, I am sitting on a bench and started to eat the chips, when my friend comes up and sits next to me.((There are no other bags of potato chips with me or around me.)) In this situation, can I say:

Q1. "Will you have one?" to mean one potato chip from the bag I hold (not two chips)
Q2. "Will you have ones?" to mean a few potato chips from the bag I hold (not one chip)

(1) yes. (2) no, you would say "Would you like some?"

It's now duly edited.

You can't offer "ones"  but the ones your friend has taken can fall to the ground if they are dropped during the handoff.

I can't follow your comment. 'during the handoff' means they each other pushing their hands while one guy is like eat this and the other is like no, thanks? I guess it's just 'passing'.

I was imagining you shaking a few out of the bag into the friend's cupped hands.

Can I replace the "shaking" in your "you shaking a few out of the bag into the friend's cupped hands" with "shake"? AND "you" with "your"? Nowadays it's hard to see the possessive case instead of objective case when it comes to representing the subject before gerund.

Why do you suppose TimR wrote: shaking a few out of the bag instead of shake? The main verb imagine is followed by a noun gerund, so no, just shake does not work. I imagine your liking this explanation as I sit here and type.

@Lambie It's noticeable that objective case is even more popular than possessive case before gerunds. Yeah, I like your explanation.

Yes, Will you have one? is fine as an offer of a single potato chip.
No, *Will you have ones? is not grammatically correct.
One can say, “Mommy, Julia ate all the chocolate ones!” The form the MOD ones (where MOD is any modifier) means “those that are MOD” as in I love the symphonies of Beethoven, especially the early, under-appreciated ones. And the situation is comparable for the ones that CLAUSE, the ones PARTICIPLE, and so on.
But for the partitive sense in your example, the proper pronoun would be some.
